# How to get Lan IP not public IP in asp.net or javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My local IP address in 192.168.0.11. 
How  can i get this using ASP.NET or Javascript.

Currently i am using the below which returns my Public IP Address

```
Dim ip As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

i googled many times but every method i got returns my Public IP.

Is it possible to get this info using asp.net or javascript.

Comment: You can't.
JavaScript doesn't deal with IP's at all, and server-side languages really have no access to local IP's.

Comment: *Server-side JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Client-side JavaScript doesn't deal with IP's at all, and server-side languages really have no access to local IP's for the simple reason that this data is not being sent to the server.

If you *really* want to obtain the local IP, you're going to have to get the user to install some kind of software on their PC.